# c# wpf - When ValueConverter is used, MVVM doesn't update UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter

I'm just learning WPF, and ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish is a calculated column in a data grid where the number displayed there is the sum of a particular property in a collection.

After a bit of googling, the approach I decided to take was to use a ValueConverter to do the calculation, but it seems that the number is never updated in the UI.  The reading I've done suggests that the PropertyChangedEvent should bubble up and this should just work but it doesn't.  I'm missing something, but I don't know what.

I wrote up a simple demo app to show what I'm doing below.  The number in the second TextBlock should be 10 before clicking the button (it is), but 6 after clicking, but it stays at 10.

How come?  Am I barking up the wrong tree?  Is there a better way to do this?  Any help would be appreciated.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BarSumConverter x:Key="BarSumConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjFoo.Bars[0].ANumber, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjFoo.Bars, Converter={StaticResource BarSumConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Button Content="Click me!" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Foo ObjFoo { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            ObjFoo = new Foo();
            ObjFoo.Bars.Add(new Bar(5));
            ObjFoo.Bars.Add(new Bar(5));

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ObjFoo.Bars[0].ANumber = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Foo.cs

```
public class Foo 
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            bars = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
        }

        ObservableCollection<Bar> bars;
        public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars
        {
            get
            {
                return bars;
            }
            set { bars = value; }
        }
    }
```

Bar.cs

```
    public class Bar : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Bar(int number)
        {
            this.ANumber = number;
        }

        private int aNumber;
        public int ANumber
        {
            get { return aNumber; }
            set
            {
                aNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("aNumber");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }
```

BarSumConverter.cs

```
    public class BarSumConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var bars = value as ObservableCollection<Bar>;
            if (bars == null) return 0;
            decimal total = 0;
            foreach (var bar in bars)
            {
                total += bar.ANumber;
            }
            return total;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the crux of the issue was that I'd assumed that updating an item inside an ObservableList that implements INotifyPropertyChanged would trigger the CollectionChanged event, but that is not the case.  So here's updated code including some of Mario's suggestions that fixes the issue:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BarSumConverter x:Key="BarSumConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjFoo.Bars[0].ANumber}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjFoo.Total}" />
        <Button Content="Click me!" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    
</Window>
```

Foo.cs

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Foo()
        {
            bars = new ObservableItemsCollection<Bar>();
            bars.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        private decimal total;
        public decimal Total
        {
            get { return total; }
            private set
            {
                if (total != value)
                {
                    total = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        ObservableItemsCollection<Bar> bars;
        void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            decimal t = 0;
            foreach (var bar in bars)
            {
                t += bar.ANumber;
            }
            this.Total = t;
        }


        public ObservableItemsCollection<Bar> Bars
        {
            get
            {
                return bars;
            }
            set { bars = value; }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Bar.cs

```
public class Bar : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Bar(int number)
        {
            this.ANumber = number;
        }

        private int aNumber;
        public int ANumber
        {
            get { return aNumber; }
            set
            {
                aNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

ObservableItemsCollection.cs

```
    public class ObservableItemsCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
        where T: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private void Handle(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, null));
        }

        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (object t in e.NewItems)
                {
                    ((T)t).PropertyChanged += Handle;
                }
            }
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (object t in e.OldItems)
                {
                    ((T)t).PropertyChanged -= Handle;
                }
            }
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, your code seems okay, except for a detail: either leave the reflection valorizing the `name` argument, or specify it manually (but remove the attribute, then).

In the latter case, you should pass the property name, not the private field. If the name is wrong, the event notification won't work. The binding mechanism will look for public properties only. Just leverage the `nameof` operator to prevent refactoring typo.

Option 1:

```
    public int ANumber
    {
        get { return aNumber; }
        set
        {
            aNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

Option 2:

```
    public int ANumber
    {
        get { return aNumber; }
        set
        {
            aNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ANumber));
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

Moreover, in both options, I'd suggest to add an equality check on the property `set`. That's to prevent useless notifications when the replacing value matches the existent one:

```
    public int ANumber
    {
        get { return aNumber; }
        set
        { 
            if (aNumber != value)
            {
                aNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged( ... );
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: I didn't try your code, so it might hide something else to patch.

UPDATE: I'd make some radical change in the `Foo` class, in order to make the things work.

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Foo()
    {
        bars = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
        bars.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    ObservableCollection<Bar> bars;
    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars
    {
        get
        {
            return bars;
        }
        //set { bars = value; }
    }

    private decimal total;
    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return total; }
        private set {
            if (total != value)
            {
                total = value;
                OnPropertyChange();
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal t = 0;
        foreach (var bar in bars)
        {
            t += bar.ANumber;
        }
        this.Total = t;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

I moved the total calculation here: converters aren't for business logic.

Also, adjust the XAML for the second `TextBox`:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjFoo.Total}" />
```

Please, notice that there's no reason to make `TwoWay` this binding.

Comment: Ahh you're right, that was a miss on the demo app.  I did try changing it though and still no luck.  Just to note the first TextBlock DOES update properly.

Comment: also, worthwhile mention about the Foo class. Either you mark the Bars property as read-only (i.e. remove the set), or follow the INotifyPropertyChange pattern as in the Bar class. Otherwise, if you replace the Bars collection, there's none notifying the framework abouyt the change.

Comment: yeah, the missing update is just because the Bars property. If you change the content of the collection, then nothing will change. Your binding is set on the Bars property. You must change approach.

Comment: All good suggestions, but none actually fixed the issue.  You did get me down the right road though so +1, thank you.  I answered with my final solution.